# Could the Pineapple Express collide with cold air, resulting in extreme snowfall?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere, precipitation

The pineapple express is a colloquial term for the strong atmospheric river produced by the polar jet stream, which drives excessive moisture and warmer air towards north-western North America.
[image: Pineapple express]

With the arrival of said atmospheric river, the coast can often see hundreds of millimeters of precipitation, sometimes resulting in flooding.

Under the right conditions, what if the pineapple express were to collide with cold arctic air along the coast, and in turn produce outrageous amounts of snow? Considering how 1mm of rainfall translates roughly to 1cm of snowfall, this could hypothetically result in meters of snow within a fairly short timespan.

Are these kind of conditions possible in theory? Or are the conditions needed to form a pineapple express mutually exclusive with the conditions needed for such cold conditions on the pacific northwest?

Comment: https://www.skimag.com/ski-resort-life/what-pineapple-express/ https://www.narcity.com/vancouver/bc-weather-is-about-to-get-hit-by-a-pineapple-express--its-going-to-bring-so-much-rain

Comment: @robbieperry22 https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242119359_Collision_of_a_Pineapple_Express_with_an_Arctic_Outbreak_over_Complex_Terrains_of_British_Columbia_Canada_-_Forecast_Challenges_and_Lessons_Learned Looks like it has been studied